# How to align text vertically next to p class image

Tags: html, css

I've got a pop out image in CSS, and i've implemented it into my html. I would just like to know how I can add text that is vertically aligned with the centre of the image (before you hover it)

EDIT: Sorry guys, I should have clarified that I want the text right of the image, with the centre of the text and centre of the image vertically aligned

I've managed to place it in the correct place using absolute position. However, what would I do if i have multiple icons using the same class?

```css
p.social-popout {
  height: 48px;
 width: 48px;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 float: left;
}
p.social-popout img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 8px;
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 float: left;
}
p.social-popout img:hover {
 margin: 0px;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="social-popout"><img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/themes/bradsknutson/images/facebook-48circle.png" /></p>
```

Comment: do you have a problem to center the text or what is your problem?

Comment: where do you want to add the text? inside the p-tag? after that?

Comment: I'm trying to add the text to the right of the image, where the texts centre and the images centre are aligned vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */
```

or use

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your **p**  is relative, and make text content **abosolute**.
Hope it will help you

```css
p.social-popout {
position: relative;
  height: 48px;
 width: 48px;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 float: left;
}
p.social-popout img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 8px;
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 float: left;
}
p.social-popout img:hover {
 margin: 0px;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 float: left;
}
p.social-popout span{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;    
transform: translate(-50%);
line-height: 0;
color: #f70000;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="social-popout"><img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/themes/bradsknutson/images/facebook-48circle.png" /><span>text</span></p>
```